# Question about BMO1 1996 Problem 2 - Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n = \frac {n+1}{n-1}(a_1+a_2+a_3+....+a_{n-1}$)

I am really not sure where to go with this.  I have book with solutions that starts with "You can manipulate the definition to get:

$a_n=\frac{2(n+1)a_{n-1}}{n}$

I'm not seeing the jump there.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem statement? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 5):

By definition 
$$a_n = \frac{n+1}{n-1}\left( a_1 + ... + a_{n-2} + a_{n-1}\right) = \frac{n+1}{n-1} \left( \frac{n-2}{n}a_{n-1} + a_{n-1}\right) = \frac{n+1}{n-1} \frac{2n-2}{n}a_{n-1}$$

So you get indeed
$$a_n = \frac{2(n+1)}{n}a_{n-1}$$

Therefore, consider the sequence $b_n = \frac{a_n}{n+1}$. It satisfies
$$b_n = 2 b_{n-1}$$

So for all $n$, you get
$$b_n = 2^n b_0$$

and you deduce finally that 
$$a_n = 2^n (n+1)a_0$$

Comment: ah, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in the sum  above  replace  $ a_1 + a_2 + ....+ a_{n-2} $  by  $\dfrac{(n-2)a_{n-1}}{n}$  and  solve for  $ a_n$ .

Answer (score 0):

The first $n-2$ terms are very similar to the definition of $a_{n-1}$; you only need to change the coefficient. This lets you prove your second equation.